# Is this the proper usage of a callback?

Tags: java, gwt

I have an `addProductButton`, click it and it brings up a `DialogBox` containing `bookNameTextBox`, `bookCategoryTextBox` and `addBookButton`. Click `addBookButton`, it inserts the `bookNameTextBox` and `bookCategoryTextBox` contents into a database. If successful, it should hide the `DialogBox` and `updateList()`

The following code works to accomplish that but I'm not sure if it's proper or if there is a better way to achieve the same results.

`Main` class

```
addProductButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    //display addBookDialogBox
    AddBookDialog abd = new AddBookDialog();
    abd.displayDialog(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            updateList();
        }
        public void onFailure() {               
        }
    });
}
});

public void updateList() {
}
```

`AddBookDialog` class

```
public class AddBookDialog extends DialogBox {

private Callback callback;

private static AddBookDialogUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
.create(AddBookDialogUiBinder.class);

interface AddBookDialogUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, AddBookDialog> {
}

public AddBookDialog() {
    setWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

public void displayDialog(Callback callback2) {
    callback = callback2;
    this.center();
}

@UiHandler("addBookButton")
void onAddBookButtonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    //save book to database
    Database db = Database.openDatabase("Store", "1.0", "My Store", 5 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(new TransactionCallback() { 
        public void onTransactionStart(SQLTransaction tx) {
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO products (bookName, bookCategory) VALUES (?, ?)", new Object[] { bookNameTextBox.getText().toString(), bookCategoryTextBox.getText().toString() }); 
        }
         public void onTransactionFailure(SQLError error) {
         }
         public void onTransactionSuccess() {
             callback.onSuccess();
         } 
    });
    this.hide();


  }
}
```

`Callback` interface

```
public interface Callback {
  void onSuccess();

  void onFailure();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the use of it here, why don't you just put `updateList();` inside the `onTransactionStart()` method ?

CallBacks are used for Asynchronism, and the TransactionCallback here already does that, so I don't see why you would use another callback inside.

And by the way, if you did need a callback, why don't you use the [AsyncCallback](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/AsyncCallback.html) provided by gwt?

EDIT :
Then the appropriate way is to make an interface with your `updateList()` method. Make your main class implement it, and change the parameter type of your `displayDialog()` method to your interface type instead of CallBack type.

Comment: `updateList()` is in `Main` class, I can't seem to access it from `onTransactionStart()` or `onTransactionSuccess`. The method `updateList()` is undefined for the type new TransactionCallback(){}